# create items and edit items created by the user not working as expected

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, item-level-permissions

I have a SharePoint List in which I have set the advanced settings as below.

[image]

Now, I have the SharePoint group that has Contribute access on the list.

My expectation is that the user should only be able to edit items that were created by them but currently, users are able to edit all the items which were created by other users.

Can anyone explain how this item-level permission from advanced settings exactly works?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the user has other permissions besides the **Contribute permissions**

[image]

Even if the page shows that the user can edit item created by other users. However, when you want to save item, the page will appear "**Sorry, you don't have access**" error

[image]

======================= **Updated Answer** ======================

**Please perform the following troubleshooting:**

`Ps: Assuming your group is GroupA.`

1.You can create a GroupB, and add users differ from GroupA in the GroupB for testing. Of course, also grant Contribute permissions to GroupB.

2.Delete GroupA from site collection permissions list, and clear browser cache, and then re-add GroupA for testing.

3.Delete GroupA from site collection permissions list, and grant Contribute permissions directly to user for testing.

Comment: I confirm user dies not have any other permission and when user click on Save it does not show any error message for permission

Comment: Hi Litt Spector. I have updated answer under initial My Answer. Hope this can help you to solve issue. Have a nice day!